# Selecting div content with htmlagilitypack 'Value cannot be null.'

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape content inside a div:

```
<div itemprop="articleBody">random, unique content in this div, different each time</div>
```

My code to try and get the content between the div above

```
 var html = "random url eachtime.com";
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);
 var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("div[@itemprop=\"articleBody\"]");
 var inntertexts = nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);
 articletext.Text = inntertexts.ToString();
```

When I visit the webpage to scrape the content between the div I get the following

> exception...Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

I have tried the xpath path like so too:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]
```

I am trying to get articleBody from the following link: view-source:http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4408856/Samsung-building-flip-phone-TWO-screens.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490

How can I fix this so I can get the div's content?

Comment: check the value of `itemprop`, you have an uppercase **B**

Comment: Yeah, I meant to add that to the div... Edditted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that div tag is inside other tags. If so, you could use `"//div[@itemprop=\"articleBody\"]"` *(slashes at the front of div tag)*.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => Task.Run(() => MainAsync(args)).Wait();

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var html = await GetResponseFromURI(new Uri("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4408856/Samsung-building-flip-phone-TWO-screens.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490"));
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@itemprop=\"articleBody\"]");
        if (nodes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<string> GetResponseFromURI(Uri uri)
    {
        var response = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

[image]

If there is not div tag with `itemprop=\"articleBody\"` at all, you will have to use null check.

Comment: Still the same exception: exception...Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: Above code works for me in console app. Could you show me the input html?

Comment: Sure thing: view-source:http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4408856/Samsung-building-flip-phone-TWO-screens.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490

Comment: I updated the answer. `"//div[@itemprop=\"articleBody\"]"` should work.